# How to compile and build openCV on Raspbian

Tags: opencv, build, compilation, raspbian

I am trying to compile and build OpenCV 2.4.13.6 in a local folder on Raspbian.

I did

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./ - DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../
make -j4
make install
```

However the modules folders in the build directory were not present (for example the file `core_c.h` of the core module could not be found). So I tried to rerun `make install` but it was failing. I went back another step and rerun `cmake ..`. I noticed it gives me warnings about many packages that cannot be found such as `gtk+-2.0` `gthread` `g-streamer` and much more.

Should I install those packages to build opencv manually?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to install dependencies manually before compiling OpenCV, although you asked for OpenCV 2, an example list of dependencies for Raspbian can be found [here](https://github.com/Tes3awy/OpenCV-3.2.0-Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi). Directly quoting from given link:

## Step 1:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo rpi-update (can be skipped, but recommended) (don't do it if you will use the RPI cam as recommended by official RPI Website)
$ sudo reboot now
```

## Step 2:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config
```

## Step 3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
```

## Step 4:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libv4l-0 libv4l-dev
```

## Step 5:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
```

## Step 6:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib
$ sudo apt-get install default-jdk ant
$ sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1-dev
$ sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

## Step 7:

install pip

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python get-pip.py
```

## Step 8:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```

## Step 9:

```
$ sudo pip install numpy
```

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get install default-jdk ant` returns an error when setting ca-certificates-java `missing "server"  JVM at /usr/lib/jvm/... /libjvm.so. Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.` Should I install it as specified here: http://www.rpiblog.com/2014/03/installing-oracle-jdk-8-on-raspberry-pi.html

Comment: I solved it resintalling certificates after a purge and installing. Now it can't find `sys/videoio.h` although lib4l-dev has been installed

Comment: I will soon try it on my raspberry pi 3 (raspbian 4), please let me know if you fix the issue in the meantime.

Comment: I am trying on odroid now and apart some other packages in both computers I get to a point where `cmake` tells me `linux/videodev.h` and `sys/videoio.h` are missing